# Update Listitem Textview on click of Listitem Button in Listview custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a listview with textview and button.

I need to update a textview when a button is clicked in a listview, and hide the button.

When I click the button, it updates the textview value. But when I scroll down and move back up, the textview content is changed back to the previous value and the button is visible.

Customadapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList cusList = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList cusList) {
        this.cusList = cusList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cusList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cusList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Bookdata data = (Bookdata) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.mytv.setText(data.getName());

        viewHolder.mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.setText("Clicked");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView mytv;
        Button mybtn;

        public ViewHolder(View item) {
            mytv = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.mytv);
            mybtn = (Button)item.findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
        }
    }
}
```

Bookdata.java

```
public class Bookdata {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Listview Code:

```
ListView books= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.books);
ArrayList bookList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Bookdata data = new Bookdata();
    data.setName("position "+i);
    bookList.add(data);
}
CustomAdapter allbookAda= new CustomAdapter(context, bookList);
books.setAdapter(allbookAda);
allbookAda.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a flag for each listitem to check which list item has been updated or not.

Basically take one flag value in your model class.

```
public class Bookdata {
private String name;
private boolean flag;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isFlag() {
    return flag;
}

public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}
```

}

add following changes in your getview method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bookdata data = (Bookdata) getItem(position);
    viewHolder.mytv.setText(data.getName());

    if(data.getFlag){
   viewHolder.mybtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    viewHolder.mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.setText("Clicked");
            cusList.get(position).setFlag(true);

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide me an example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common behavior as listview uses recycled views, the above answers are correct but I prefer a more cleaner approach using DataBinding